# Will fgets always read from the beginning of the string?

Tags: c, fgets

I need to use fgets to read multiple lines of stdin that are separated by newlines (ex.

```
Hello
world
!
```

). If I include fgets in a for loop, will it read from the first line during every iteration? If so, how would I go about achieving this?

Comment: No. It reads from the current file position until (and including) the next newline, or the buffer size limit. If the limit was reached before a newline was read, the next call will read the remainder of the line, or not, subject to the same constraints. The idiomatic loop is `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fptr) != NULL) printf("%s", buffer);`

Comment: In general, and unless there's a line that won't fit in your buffer, each call to `fgets` will read the next line in the file.  So it's quite common to call `fgets` in a loop, in which case one trip through the loop will read and process one line.  (Again, unless theres a line that won't fit.)

Comment: `fgets()` reads lines from opened files, not from strings... It's important to use the right terms... A `string` is a null-terminated array of characters in memory... `fgets()` guarantees that whatever it may have loaded from the file will be a null terminated `string` (if successful)...

Answer (score 1):

> Will fgets always read from the beginning of the string?

No.  `fgets()` reads based on the current state, which might be partially into a line of user input.  It does not somehow magically go back to the beginning - just starts from where the *stream* is currently positioned..

`fgets()` does not read *strings*.  It read a *line* of input and converts the input into a *string*. [@Fe2O3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73506690/will-fgets-always-read-from-the-beginning-of-the-string/73508251#comment129807861_73506690).  It does not stop when a *null character* is read.

`fgets()` reads until:

- An `'\n'` is read.
- The size - 1 passed in `fgets()` is met.
- An end-of-file or input error is encountered (e.g. wrong stream mode, parity error, phase of the moon input error, ...)

> If I include fgets in a for loop, will it read from the first line during every iteration? If so, how would I go about achieving this?

First before using `fgets()`, be sure the entire prior line was read.
2nd: if this line of input after using `fgets()` was incomplete, finish it.

```
char buf[N];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) {
  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  if (len + 1 == sizeof buf && buf[sizeof buf - 2] != '\n')) {
    // User input is not complete, read rest of line.
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar() != '\n') ** ch != EOF) {
      ;
    }
  }
```

**Pedantic**: `fgets()` is not a great input function if input might include *null characters*.  In that case, more advance techniques are needed.